# WCF Services and Factory Design Pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am trying to implement factory pattern in WCF but it does not work. 
I created a WCFServiceLibrary project called `TestServiceLibrary`. then I created wcf service called `EmployeeService` which has `IEmployeeService` interface.
I defined methods `ViewAttendance`, `SaveAttendance` in `IEmployeeService` interface with implementation in `EmployeeService` class. I then created a client web application that consume `EmployeeService` by creating a service reference called "EmployeeServiceRef" and in the code behind Default.aspx.cs I call the following method

```
EmployeeServiceRef.IEmployeeService obj = new EmployeeServiceRef.EmployeeServiceClient();
obj.ViewAttendance();
```

and it displayed the expected results. Then in the `TestServiceLibrary`  project i created another class called `EmployeeCardReaderService` which implements the `IEmployeeService` interface  because it will also have `ViewAttendance` method but with different implementation so basically created another WCF service  without creating a new Interface and configured as
a new service in web.config. Then in the client application I created another service reference

**EmployeeCardReaderServiceRef**:

```
EmployeeCardReaderServiceRef.IEmployeeService obj2 = new EmployeeCardReaderServiceRef.EmployeeServiceClient();
```

and when i call `obj2.ViewAttendance();` it will call `ViewAttendance()` method of `EmployeeService` and not `EmployeeCardReaderService`. 
Could any one tell me please whether its possible to implement factory design pattern in wcf services?. If it is then whats the correct way because its not working for me. Also can we apply factory pattern to  asmx webservices?

```
namespace TestServiceLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace="http://www.test.com")]
    public interface IEmployeeService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string ViewAttendance();
        [OperationContract]
        string ViewEmployee();
        [OperationContract]
        string ViewDetails();
    }
}


namespace TestServiceLibrary
{
    public class EmployeeService : IEmployeeService
    {
        public string ShowWork()
        {
            return "";
        }

        #region IEmployeeService Members

        public string ViewAttendance()
        {
            /* TODO. Implementation specific to Device */
            return "EmployeeService Attendance";
        }
        public string ViewEmployee()
        {
            return "Employee Number 1";
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEmployeeService Members


        public string ViewDetails()
        {
            return "Employee Details are as follows";
        }

        #endregion
    }

    class EmployeeCardReaderService : IEmployeeService
    {
        #region IEmployeeService Members

        public string ViewAttendance()
        {
           /*TODO:
            Implementation specific to card reader customer
            */

            return "EmployeeCardReaderService Attendance";
        }

        public string ViewEmployee()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public string ViewDetails()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

```xml
      <service name="TestServiceLibrary.EmployeeService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TestServiceLibrary.IEmployeeService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/TestServiceLibrary/EmployeeService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
      <service name="TestServiceLibrary.EmployeeCardReaderService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="TestServiceLibrary.IEmployeeService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost/TestServiceLibrary/EmployeeCardReaderService/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
```

Comment: Factory pattern or not, "configured as a new service in web.config" did not work correctly. Post that part and we may be able to help.

Comment: I've added more information

Answer (score 0):

```
new EmployeeCardReaderServiceRef.EmployeeServiceClient();
```

should read

```
new EmployeeCardReaderServiceRef.EmployeeCardReaderServiceClient();
```

The way it is now, you are calling the same service through two references.

Comment: EmployeeCardReaderServiceClient is not in the list when i call new EmployeeCardReaderServiceRef. then i have three options EmployeeServiceClient, IEmployeeService, IEmployeeServiceChannel even though i've configured reference to the new service

Comment: @waqas: thats because your `EmployeeCardReaderService` class is not under `public` scope, hence its respective client refence was never created. just add this `public` specifier, it should work as you intend it to :)

Comment: @dreamweiver: declaring public did not make any difference